# Redirect Loop in Regex Moving to HTTPS

Tags: htaccess, regex

First, this site has been running on HTTPS for over 6 months with a green address bar and all. It was only recently I was reading on Bing Webmaster Tools that redirect loops were a problem on this site. I decided to use the IIS SEO bot to check it for errors. The final report showed over 5000 redirect loops errors (WHAT?).

I have all the usual settings applied correctly under Settings > General but took it a step further and added the DEFINE HOME and DEFINE SITE URL's in the wp-config file.

I am using AskApache to test my response headers here: http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/http-headers-tool/

Besides the redirect loop, I am getting a "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" response when the browser terminates the loop. I need a regex pro to tell me why this code is causing a loop. Wordpress.org moderators seem to think the code is fine, but getting this on 2 client sites also that are on different hosting platforms (All are Apache 2.2):

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

One site in question is https://jadecomputerservices.com

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: This issue came about from many warnings in Bing Webmaster Tools. I discovered that I had added these sites to "My Sites" before I moved them over to HTTPS. I had to delete the sites from BWT and add them back again. It now shows that they're being crawled correctly.

Another coder over at https://www.codementor.io showed me 2 other header checking sites that showed correct "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" responses. Those sites were: tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker and web-sniffer.net

Be sure to check multiple sources if you have the same issue. Good luck!